# Correct e.preventDefault() on a submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="keyword" value="keyword">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

I was wondering if anyone could show me with jquery how I could put an e prevent default on the submit button, so that if the submit button is triggered I can get it to instead do something else other than submit, say have an alert.

So far I have this:

```
function submit_hit() {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('History set');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('form input:submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('History set');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/XZcjv/)

Comment: Good point, added another alternative. And +1 to you for the comment!

Comment: Better if you bind  `pressKey` with `enter`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

### Option 1 -

```
$('form').on('submit',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   alert('Prevented!');
});
```

This function will prevent the form submit. It will fire when the form is submited. With `click` or with `Enter` key.

If you have many forms can be good to use a ID on this selector, like `$('#form_id').on('submit',function(e){//...ect`

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jx9BZ/)**

### Option 2 -

```
$('form input[type=submit]').on('click',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
    alert('Prevented!');
});
```

This function will also prevent the form submit. It will fire when the input button is `clicked`.

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jx9BZ/1/)**

Comment: It's ok only if you are not planning to submit the form later programmatically with `$('form').submit();`.